# Entrek CodeSnitch with Windows Mobile 5/6

Tags: c++, windows-mobile

I have emailed Entrek and they seem to be asleep.

Does anyone else here use Entrek CodeSnitch?  If so, have you found a way to use it with Windows Mobile 5, 6, or 6.1 ?

I *really* need to verify my application doesn't have any memory leaks, etc.  And CodeSnitch does a great job of it.  But only with Windows Mobile 2003.   :/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What's not working?  Is it a client connectivity issue?

The older version used PlatMan for a communications layer, which is problematic from a Visual Studio standpoint (which ships with CoreCon), but if you have any tool installed that has Platman (eVC, Platform Builder) then that should still work fine since WinMo 5.x and 6.x are still based on CE 5.0.

I do know that Entrek has a newer version in beta (I have it) so you might try pinging them again.  They tend to be pretty busy, but I've always gotten responses (though I know them well and personally, so that might not be any indicator for you).

I also see that they have their phone number [posted on their web page](http://www.entrek.com/support.htm).  I'd give them a call.  I do recall them saying the new version is supposed to address WinMo issues (I rarely use WinMo proper) so it's definitely worth a try.

Comment: Hi Chris,

I run CodeSnitch stand-alone and when it asks for "Select a Windows CE device", the only option I have is Pocket Pc 2003.  Does your Beta edition have WinMo 5/6 support as optional devices to connect to?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, I emailed Entrek again asking for support on getting the Beta of Codesnitch or *some* support on allowing me to connect and debug WinMo 5/6/6.1 devices.  Their web site is awfully dated (2003!?) and nothing changes.  I wondered if they were even still in business.

Comment: They're certainly still around.  I'm out of my office, so I can't readily check on the features of the beta.  I'd give them a call.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used CodeSnitch.  But I have had success using the [Application Verifier Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=D275348A-D937-4D88-AE25-28702C78748D&displaylang=en) to identify my leaks in WM5 and 6.

Getting it up and running can be a bit of a pain.  But I find it to be a good tool and the price is right.

[Here](http://www.windowsfordevices.com/articles/AT5485766681.html)'s a tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I've used CodeSnitch on windows mobile 5, 6 and 6.1 devices with no problems.

Make sure you have the v1.4 installed and applied the v1.4 patch which is referenced [here](http://www.entrek.com/products/Readme.htm).

Like ctackle says, you need an older communications layer called CoreCon.  I've also found [CETK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=40B7CEDB-DC8B-4503-8DC9-E75F8E8496C1&displaylang=en) has CoreCon in it as well and it's not as big as eVC or Platform builder.

You need to setup the device connection settings to use ActiveSync (both transport and startup server), it does not seem to matter what the connection is called so something like Pocket PC will work fine.

The other gotcha I found is that you need to edit the codesnitch and procman shortcuts and add "/targetcpu:armv4i" to the command line arguments for them to work on WM devices.

I have also found them recently to be non-responsive to support emails as well :(